# How to fix Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Ethernet Controller 1 Gbps adapter now limited to 100 Mpbs speed on download only?

Tags: networking, bios

On two separate laptops, both are HP OMEN Laptop 15-dc1xxx SKU 7TK52UA#ABA, upgrade from 18.04.3 LTS to 18.04.5 breaks Gigabit speeds. Gigabit speeds worked fine in 18.04.3 Updated weeks apart when running kernel 5.4.0-42-generic the download speeds for the RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller. The download speed is now limited to roughly 100-130 Mbps and upload is still able to achieve 1 Gbps (1000 Mbps).

Have **AT&T Gigapower (gigabit up and down)**, and have replaced gateway thinking it was originally the issue. This has been proven not to be the source of the issue.

Trying to get Gigabit speed back wo/ having to roll back kernel version.

[system + connection info + speed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aavdZ.png)

Here is more system info:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"

$ sudo grep -e [0-9] -e [A-Z] /sys/class/dmi/id/{chassis_{type,vendor,version,serial},product_{family,name,serial,sku,uuid,version}}
/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type:10
/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_vendor:HP
/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_version:Chassis Version
/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_serial:xxxxxxxxxx
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_family:103C_5335KV HP OMEN
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_name:OMEN by HP Laptop 15-dc1xxx
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial:xxxxxxxxx
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_sku:7TK52UA#ABA
/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid:39444335-3833-5a36-5a4c-040e3c8a6d6c

$ lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 16)

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: 04:0e:3c:8a:6d:6c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.80 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84404000-84404fff memory:84400000-84403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 1a
       serial: 50:e0:85:f2:b5:ca
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:84300000-84303fff

$ ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes

$ nmcli -g 802-3-ethernet -m multiline con show "Wired connection 1" 
802-3-ethernet.port:
802-3-ethernet.speed:0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:yes
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:04:0E:3C:xx:xx:xx
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:
802-3-ethernet.mtu:auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:default
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:

$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
F.12
```

**Update:**
Tested Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Live.

- Speeds on Live - 123.7 Mbps/down & 321.6 Mbps/up
- On 18.04.3 & 18.04.5 upload was 850-950 Mbps/up.

**Update:** Upgraded one of the laptops to 20.04.1 LTS to re-confirm

- Wired Speeds after upgrade 125 Mbps/down & 884.7 Mbps/up
- Same results with "Link negotation" set to ignore, automatic or 1Gb/s Full
- Wireless Speeds (fyi) 196 Mbps/down & 370 Mbps/up

**Update:** Upgraded system info

```
root@hpomenlpt02:/var/log# dmidecode -s bios-version
F.13

root@hpomenlpt02:/var/log# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"

Sep  2 00:04:21 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  125.750914] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-300:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-300:00, irq=IGNORE)
Sep  2 00:04:21 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  125.862804] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
Sep  2 00:04:21 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  125.883048] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Sep  2 00:04:21 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  126.068202] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Sep  2 00:04:21 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  126.084566] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
Sep  2 00:04:24 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  128.849144] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
Sep  2 00:04:24 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  128.849172] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.456614] wlo1: authenticate with a6:98:13:e4:9d:e3
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.461971] wlo1: send auth to a6:98:13:e4:9d:e3 (try 1/3)
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.497916] wlo1: authenticated
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.501195] wlo1: associate with a6:98:13:e4:9d:e3 (try 1/3)
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.506221] wlo1: RX AssocResp from a6:98:13:e4:9d:e3 (capab=0x511 status=0 aid=91)
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.508531] wlo1: AP has invalid WMM params (AIFSN=1 for ACI 2), will use 2
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.508535] wlo1: AP has invalid WMM params (AIFSN=1 for ACI 3), will use 2
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.514155] wlo1: associated
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.527588] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 127 (127 - 0) dBm as advertised by a6:98:13:e4:9d:e3
Sep  2 00:04:25 hpomenlpt02 kernel: [  129.628042] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
```

**Update:** Laptop Model

- Sku was up at the top: 7TK52UA#ABA
- Model: HP Omen 15-dc1057nr
- Kernel: 5.4.0-45-generic
- HP Latest Firmware: F.18 Rev.A
- https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/omen-by-hp-15-dc1000-laptop-pc-series/26122182/model/30206210?sku=7TK52UA

**Update:** Firmware Upgrade from F.12 to F.18 Rev. A

Reminder: Have two HP Omen 15-dc1057nr laptops

- One was upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS during testing.

Testing on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

- Status: Succcessful; gigabit speeds working again w/ BIOS F.18 Rev. A

Testing on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

- Status: Failed; at BIOS F.18 and when using either r8169 or r8168
- Still experiencing slow down on Fibre/Gigabit connection
- 130.2 Mbps/down & 868.6 Mbps/up

See the note in comments back on r8168 below for 20.04.1 LTS.

Follow the "Recover the BIOS using a USB recovery drive" -> "Create a USB recovery drive" procedure at the link [how-to](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02693833).

This particular HP Omen, 15-dc1057nr, did not have options in the BIOS menus to update the BIOS nor to update the BIOS from a local media.
To force the HP Omen to access the HP BIOS Update screen do the following:

- Press and hold both the **Windows** key and the **B** key simultaneously.
- While continuing to hold those keys, press and hold the **Power** button for 2 to 3 seconds.
- Release the **Power** button and continue pressing the **Windows** and **B** keys until the HP BIOS Update screen appears. (Note: there were a few times I had to let go of the Windows and B keys in this step for the screen to appear; go figure HP)
- If any issues are encountered with this, then refer to the same link above under the "Recover the BIOS using a key press combination" section for things to check.

**Update:** 2nd Laptop previously running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS upgraded 20.04.1 LTS

- Upgraded from 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS with no issues
- Gigabit download speeds still limited to ~ 130 Mbps/down
- Upload speeds still ~ 800+ Mbps/up
- Tested with wired gigabit connection using "ignore, automatic, and manual 1 Gb/s Full" - still no better than ~ 130 Mbps/down
- Created live USBs and tested the following:

  - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Live - Result: 850+ Mbps/down & 900+ Mbps/up
  - Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Live - Result: inconclusive

    - Speed test 1: 907 Mbps/down & 886 Mbps/up
    - Speed test 2: 126 Mbps/down & 864 Mbps/up
    - Speed test 3: 122 Mbps/down & 880 Mbps/up
    - syslog kernel message reported link was up at 1 Gbps/Full Flow Control off
  - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Live - Result: 130~ Mbps/down & 850+ Mbps/up
- Validated BIOS Firmware is at F18:

  ```
  $ sudo cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version
  F.18
  ```
- To be certain, validated the DMI info was the equivalent to the 2nd HP Omen dc-1057nr

  ```
  $ sudo grep -e [0-9] -e [A-Z] /sys/class/dmi/id/{chassis_{type,vendor,version,serial},product_{family,name,serial,sku,uuid,version}}
  /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type:10
  /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_vendor:HP
  /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_version:Chassis Version
  /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_serial:xxxxxxxxxxx
  /sys/class/dmi/id/product_family:103C_5335KV HP OMEN
  /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name:OMEN by HP Laptop 15-dc1xxx
  /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial:xxxxxxxxxxx
  /sys/class/dmi/id/product_sku:7TK52UA#ABA
  /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid:39444335-3833-5a36-5a4c-040e3c8a6d6c
  ```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Also, boot to a Ubuntu Live 20.04.1 DVD/USB and see if things improve. Report back.

Comment: Updated per request with results from Ubuntu Live 20.04.1 + Upgrade testing.

Comment: I'm trying to locate the newest BIOS for your HP laptop. I need the EXACT model #. Also, show me `uname -r`.

Comment: Many thanks! Upgrading the BIOS Firmware from F.12 to F.18 Rev. A indeed resolved the issue. There was no need to switch to r8168. The r8168-dkms driver was purged, and Gigabit speeds continue to work for both down/up. Took the easy route and built a USB recovery drive on Win 10 to save time. See updates in question above for how to create the USB Recovery Media and run it on power up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

HP Omen 15-dc1057nr

You have BIOS version F.12 (or F.13).

There's a newer BIOS available, version F.18 Rev.A, dated 8/3/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/omen-by-hp-15-dc1000-laptop-pc-series/26122182/model/30206210).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Note: BIOS rollback document is [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02693833).

**Ethernet**

Let's try a different ethernet driver.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms`

`reboot`

Retest download speeds.

**Update #1:**

Ubuntu 20.04.1 and BIOS update to F.18 required for gig speeds.

**Update #2:**

```
#!/bin/sh

# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1779817
#
# Attached is a work-around for the in-kernel driver that is as unhacky as I can make it.

# filename: r8169_disable_msi

# Drop it in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top and chmod a+x it. Add 'r8169_disable_msi'
# to your kernel command line (/etc/default/grub, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
# usually.) 

# Remember to update-initramfs and update-grub as necessary.

# sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
# sudo update-grub
# reboot

# For the moment it disables MSI on everything with the ID 0x10ec:0x8168, as there seems to
# be no way to get the MAC version from userspace - and certainly not before the driver is
# loaded. Other PCI IDs may need adding..

# Still hoping we can cherry pick the in-driver workaround for bionic...?

PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}
case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

disable_msi () {
    for i in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*; do 
        if [ $(cat $i/vendor) = "0x10ec" -a $(cat $i/device) = "0x8168" ]; then
            echo 0 >$i/msi_bus
        fi
    done
}

for x in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
        case ${x} in
        r8169_disable_msi)
        disable_msi
        break
                ;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: See the results for Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS above. Still failing after firmware upgrade as well as firmware upgrade + changing driver from r8169 to r8168.

Comment: @FateBennett If I read your updates/comments correctly, one laptop with F.18 BIOS and 20.04.1 works fine now, and the other laptop with F.18 BIOS and 18.04.5 still fails. Am I correct that we should update the latter to 20.04.1 also? Just curious, on the latter, if you boot to a prior kernel, does it work then?

Comment: the latter will need to be either updated to 20.04.1 or booted back into 18.04.3. Since actively working on the 18.04.5 laptop have to pause till Friday to avoid any new surprises. Will try booting to prior kernel first, 18.04.3, but ultimately looking to upgrade to 20.04.

Comment: The other laptop is not playing as nicely. Upgrade to 20.04.1 was clean, but still no Gigabit down speeds. Live testing just left additional questions. Doing one last live test with 18.04.5 to see if get same results as 20.04.1. See updates in question. Continue troubleshooting and looking for any clues on system.

Comment: @FateBennett Just for fun, try two things... 1) If you have Windows installed, boot it, and for the ethernet card, initiate a repair, and retest. 2) In the new BIOS, initiate a set "back to factory BIOS" settings, and retest. Report back.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking the same. Kept the original M.2 w/ Win10 on it just for a special occasion like this one! ;-) Powering down and trying what you recommended. Thx.

Comment: Tried the two items: (one not in the list)
1) in new BIOS set back to factory BIOS - no change
2) ipv6 - disabled; no change; set back to automatic and got a bump to gigabit speed for download for a single test; after that first test back to 130 Mbps/down
Switching back to Windows drive; just wanted to test these two options first before switching back to Windows.

Comment: @FateBennett Didn't "troubleshoot/repair" ethernet card from Windows?

Comment: Re-performing on Win10; eliminating ipv6 as a contributor while still on linux.

Comment: @FateBennett Do you have QoS enabled in your router?

Comment: @FateBennett Status please...

Comment: troubleshoot/repair on Windows didn't work.
Additionally trying the 5.8 kernel from HWE on 20.04.02 LTS did not solve the issue either.

Comment: @FateBennett Long time no see. Still having problems? Refresh my memory... is the problem only on one machine, or two machines? On each machine, do `lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet` and edit that output into your question.

Comment: Been a while! Got busy living and working... Problem is with 2 hp-omen-15-dc1057nr laptops with Realtek NICs.

sudo lshw -class network        
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s

Comment: Things tried to date:
NetworkManager config: MTU from Auto to 1500
NetworkManager config: Link negotiation from Automatic to Manual; speeds 100 Mb/s, 1 Gb/s, Duplex half and full
Connection priority: -999
IPv6 set to ignore
IPv6 set to disable
BIOS Firmware update HP-BIOS-F21_Rev_A--20201207
Installing r8168-dkms & and using r8168 driver in kernel instead of r8169 (had to revert)
Attempted to dowload drivers from Realtek and compile them, but the site would allow download of the Linux 64-bit driver.
HWE 5.8.0-50 kernel tested; regressed back to 5.4.0-72-generic

Comment: Weird thing, on the first internet connection after opening a browser (doesn't matter which i.e. firefox, chromium, chrome),  going to google's speed test shows optimal speeds 700+ down & 800+ up mbps. After first test it consistently drops back down to ~125 mbps down, but still hits 800+ up mbps. 

Only thing notable regarding this adapter on one machine is:
RX errors 0  dropped 7180

Doesn't occur on the other machine.

To make sure it wasn't switch or cable, plugged same cable + switch into Dell Latitude 7490 w/ gigabit adapter. Speed test showed 925 down / 876 up mbps.

Comment: @FateBennett You didn't show me `lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet` from EACH machine. Edit that output into your question please. Are you using DSL, fiber, or what kind of Internet connection?

Comment: Updated the original question with the lspci info. The kind of internet connection was in the initial info above. Bolded it. AT&T Gigapower (Gp up & down). Thanks.

Comment: @FateBennett Thanks for the info. However, you forgot the "-nn" part of the `lspci` command, and it contains info I need to see. Also, please install `iputils-tracepath` and then do `tracepath www.ebay.com` or `tracepath www.google.com` and edit that output into your question. Thanks.

Comment: The output for the "-nn" is above in the "Here is more system info:"

Comment: @FateBennett See Update #2 in my answer. You may need `r8168-dkms`.